# Confusion with Generics

Tags: c++, qt

I have

```
class Foo : public QFrame {...}
```

and in the module when this class is used, I have

```
QWidget* screen = this->parentWidget();
Foo* foo = (Foo*) screen->findChild<QFrame*>("foo1"); // foo1 is the name of the control from .ui file
```

and this works. If I change it to

```
QWidget* screen = this->parentWidget();
Foo* foo = screen->findChild<Foo*>("foo1"); // foo1 is the name of the control from .ui file
```

I get this linker error

> Error 4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static
>   struct QMetaObject const Foo::staticMetaObject"
>   (?staticMetaObject@Foo@@2UQMetaObject@@B) Foo.obj

What's the difference between the two snippets and why does the first one work and the second one doesn't?

Comment: They're called "templates" in C++.

Comment: Side note, in C++ they are not called generics.  These are templates.

Comment: It's not that they're not *called* generics. They're *not* generics. One of the fundamental differences is the behavior we see in this question.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Oh completely. It's a lot easier to search for help on something if you know what it is *called*.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because **[Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)** is missing on **Foo** class

From Qt Documenation

```
Adding a Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() makes the type 
known to all template based functions
```

Something like

```
class Foo : public QFrame
{
 //everything
}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo)
```

Comment: So, do I have to change Foo's declaration  to `class Q_DECLARE_METATYPE  Foo : public QFrame {...}` ?

Comment: Typically you do `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo)` outside of your class

Answer (score 1):

Your class Foo is probably missing the Q_OBJECT macro.
Add it and, if you use QMake, add the header to the HEADERS list and rerun qmake.

Comment: I do have QOBJECT macro for Foo.